# Blocked country with one IP allowed (GEOIP Conf.)

Tags: apache, geoip

Well it's not a real "programing question", but a "config one".
I've an Apache Web server and I use the GEOIP module. My website must be visible only by one country but also by 1 IP from an other country (so from a blocked country).
Actually my geoip.conf looks like that:

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>-
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPOutput All  
GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
</IfModule>
<Location />
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE XX AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
</Location>
```

Where XX is the code of the allowed country

How can I add only one allowed IP from a blocked country?

Answer (score 1):

Find the way to do that:

```
  <IfModule mod_geoip.c>
  GeoIPEnable On
  GeoIPOutput All
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat

  <Location />
  #SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE XX AllowCountry
  SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CA AllowCountry
  # here list of other countries
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=AllowCountry
  # Here the IP we want to allow, even if it's from a blocked country
  Allow from 222.222.88.99
  </Location>

  </IfModule>
```